# Install Racket package only if not installed

Tags: package, racket

I can install a Racket package with:

```
raco pkg install <pkg-name>
```

If the package is not installed, it installs it. If the package is already installed however, it will complain that the package is already installed. While this is fine, is there a better way to check if a package is installed, and only try to install it if its not already installed?

For context, I want this because I have a (non-package) Racket project that relies on certain packages being installed. I could put them in an info.rkt file, but as far as I can tell, these won't get installed unless I try to install the project as a package, which doesn't make sense for this domain.

So, is there anyway to determine if a Racket package is installed? Additionally, can I use this information to only install a package if its not already installed?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in fact you can. If you are using a shell program or makefile (basically, using the `raco pkg` tool from the command line), you can pass it the `--skip-installed` parameter. This will only try to install the package if its not already installed. So you could do something like this in a mace file:

```
all: # Replace spaces here with tabs, because make...
    raco pkg install --skip-installed <important-pkg>
    <rest-of-makefile>
```

Alternatively, if you are looking for an 'in Racket' solution, you can use the [`installed-pkg-table`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/pkg/lib.html?q=installed-pkg-table#%28def._%28%28lib._pkg%2Flib..rkt%29._installed-pkg-table%29%29) function to get a hash table containing all of the installed packages. From there, its easy enough to do a `hash-has-key?` to see if the package is in the table. From there, you can use [`pkg-install-command`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/pkg/Functions_for_raco_pkg.html?q=pkg-install-command#%28def._%28%28lib._pkg%2Fmain..rkt%29._pkg-install-command%29%29) to install the package. Your total code will look something like this:

```
(unless (hash-has-key? (installed-pkg-table) "<important-pkg>")
  (pkg-install-command #:deps 'search-auto i))
```

I should note that there is a slight chance that the package database will change between searching for the key and installing the package. If that is important to you, check out [`with-pkg-lock`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/pkg/lib.html?q=with-pkg-lock#%28form._%28%28lib._pkg%2Flib..rkt%29._with-pkg-lock%29%29)